# IInAppBillingService show a warning - method getInterfaceDescriptor is never used locally - How to remove?

Tags: android, warnings, in-app-billing

I know this is a warning, and not a problem, but I want to keep my projects clean.

Is there a way to remove this warning from IInAppBillingService?

```
The method getInterfaceDescriptor() from the type IInAppBillingService.Stub.Proxy is never used locally IInAppBillingService.java
```